# Can I write a function that can either return one data type or another in C?

Tags: c

How can I make a function that either returns zero or an array of numbers. My function should test if the input string with a string two hexadecimal numbers separated by a space, such as this string: `"a48 2b4"`. If it does qualify, return an int array of the two numbers, if not, like if it has non hex characters or too many spaces, return 0. How can I do this in c?

Comment: You can return a NULL pointer in the case of an error.

Comment: ... or pass a pointer to an array be filled and return an integer as status.

Comment: You cannot directly return an array in any case -- you would need to return a pointer (to the first element) instead -- so a null pointer would be a pretty natural representation of the alternative to "an array".

Comment: There's the whole rather complex issue of returning an array in C. There are at least half a dozen different ways to do it, and answer depends on which one you choose, which depends on your requirements.

Comment: You could try returning a struct with pointer to a malloced array, and integer length. Zero and/or negative length could mean an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you cannot directly return an array in any case, you're going to need to modify your plan.  Consider first that the two alternative returns you describe are largely unrelated -- one is data, the other a status code.  They do not fit well as alternatives, and that's one of the reasons you are struggling.

A nice, clean design would follow from the alternative @try-catch-finally suggested in comments: let the caller pass (a pointer to) an array to the function as an argument.  On success, the function fills in the first two elements (relying on the caller to have provided a pointer suitable for that).  The function's actual return value can then be a status code.  I guess the way you're thinking about it, that would be 0 on failure and something else (1?) on success, though that's backwards from the way most standard library functions do it.

Example:

```
int parseHex(const char *str, int *parsed_result) {
    // ...
    if (success) {
        parsed_result[0] = hex0;
        parsed_result[1] = hex1;
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

There are at least two other ways you could approach the problem, but this one is clean and consistent, and does not saddle the caller with any new responsibility for freeing dynamically-allocated memory.

Comment: What does parsed mean?

Comment: @Asadefa, do not get hung up on variable names.  But "parsing" is the process of extracting data from text -- in this case, two `int`s.  "Parsed" in the parameter name conveys that such a procedure is how the values to be recorded were computed.

Comment: Parsing is useful, then.

Answer (score 1):

I could also use a **Union**. A union can store two or more types of values.

```
union OptionalInt {
    int Value;
    bool IsNull;
};

union OptionalInt ParseHex(char *Str) {
    //...
    if(/*Success*/) {
        return (union OptionalInt){/*Value*/, 0};
    }else{
        return (union OptionalInt){0, 1};
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure you can.  But a function that returns a union type returns a union type.    That's one type, not several.  Note, too, that your example is flawed, and does not match your requirement to return an `int` array.  A union can indeed have an array member, but yours does not.  Also, the union literals you present do not mean what you seem to think they mean.  Something like this can definitely be made to work, but the technique described in my answer is more idiomatic.